# Remove dead host from memsql followers list

Tags: singlestore

Recently a memsql leaf had a major failure and was not able to be brought up again.  The corresponding instance was terminated (aws instance)  and the ip of the node / leaf id does not appear in the leaves node anymore. However the ip/id appears in the followers list   memsql-ops agent-list -q -r follower     shows all my followers + this one that i want to remove.

Trying to run unmonitor on the specific id fails

memsql-ops memsql-unmonitor Af...
      Failed to find MemSQL node matching id Af....     ->  i assume this is normal given the fact the the specific instance was terminated

Is there any way to get rid of this id from the followers list and webUI?

Comment: Looks [the docs](https://docs.memsql.com/docs/memsql-unmonitor) have a `--remove-leaf` option, have you tried using that flag? There's also [memsql-delete](https://docs.memsql.com/docs/memsql-delete) which supports a force flag.

Comment: memsql-ops memsql-unmonitor "Afec0d7" --remove-leaf
usage: memsql-ops ...
memsql-ops: error: unrecognized arguments: --remove-leaf

Answer (score 0):

```
memsql-ops agent-uninstall --force
```

https://docs.memsql.com/docs/agent-uninstall

Unless you are using HA the data on the leaf is likely gone and the MA has dropped it (if you have enterprise this would not happen). So you were just seeing ops -a separate process- trying to reach the ops-agent and failing. Since agent-uninstall expects to hear back from the agent, it will not succeed without --force

Comment: memsql-ops agent-uninstall --agent-id "Afec0d7" 
This will completely delete the MemSQL Ops agent running on 10.xxxx:9000, along with all of its data
If you want to delete this MemSQL Ops agent, please type the word DELETE: DELETE
2016-09-28 13:45:44: Jfd0b5c [INFO] Deleting MemSQL Ops agent Afec0d7ea261249f78dd1a2bad5f10c68
2016-09-28 13:45:44: Jfd0b5c [ERROR] Agent Afec0d7ea261249f78dd1a2bad5f10c68 does not have any SSH credentials

Uninstall failed for agent IDs: 
Afec0d7ea261249f78dd1a2bad5f10c68

Comment: I assume the SSH error is normal given the fact that the host does not exist anymore

Comment: AH you saved me!   the --flag was the key here . Thanks a million !

Answer (score 0):

memsql-ops agent-uninstall --agent-id  --force

The --force does the trick here